# Am I ready for 300km?

Tags: road-bike, training

I've heard that once you've ridden 200km, the bigger distances are just about proper nutrition and hydration. Is this true? I want to know if I'm ready for a bit hilly 300km, if my current max is 200km.

I did 200km yesterday and was feeling ok afterwards - just a bit tired. After my 200km a week ago I was much more tired and in pain, so there's a progress.

Is there a big leap between 200km and 300km rides?

Comment: If you have to ask, then the answer is *no*.

Comment: That is jumping from a ~8ish hour ride to an ~11-12ish hour ride (assuming 26kph average) . Exhaustion may start to set in even with proper nutrition & hydration. Can you bail if needed? What would worry me more is the pain. What kind of pain? Where? You might have problems with bike fit, pedaling style, your saddle & chamois. That is a bit farther than I've ever ridden. While training for a 130k charity ride, the furthest I'd ridden beforehand was 88k & had no problem given proper nutrition & water. But your ride is a big difference from mine.

Comment: Is this a solo 300km or will you be in a group? Drafting and riding with a group makes a big difference in how far you can ride.

Answer (score 4):

If you've managed 200 km without problems you can also ride 300 km. As usual don't ride too fast and keep yourself well fed.
1st big leap is usually between 400 km and 600 km, because after 400 km you will (typically) need to sleep.

Comment: Thanks, I think I'll give it a shot and a weekend. It's most probably solo ride, I want this to be my own achievment.

Answer (score 2):

Yes!  Go for it.  What's the worst that can happen?  If you don't finish, then you know that you're pushing your limits, and you will have learned more about how to do it better next time.

Just make sure you take enough food, some warm/dry clothes, and you know where the bailout options are.

I reckon that if you don't know all the answers in advance, then it's a real adventure and when you complete you'll be all the more happy that you gave it a go.